# How to check for value of field in a trigger

Tags: sql, postgresql, triggers

I'm trying to check for a field missing during an UPDATE statement. I was thinking something like this

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION UPDATED_BY_TRIGGER()
RETURNS TRIGGER AS
$BODY$
BEGIN
    IF NEW."updated_by" IS NULL THEN
        RAISE EXCEPTION 'updated_by is missing in UPDATE to %', TG_TABLE_NAME;
    END IF;   
    RETURN NEW;
END;
$BODY$ LANGUAGE PLPGSQL;
```

Here's the catch: the value in the DB for the field is already not NULL (because it has a NOT NULL constraint), so I can't use NEW."updated_by". I am able to run UPDATE statements that don't change the value of updated_by right now. I want to raise an exception when this happens.

Comment: Due to `MVCC` `updated_by` will always be in the `UPDATE` as an `UPDATE` is a `DELETE` old tuple(row) `INSERT` new tuple. The `NEW."updated_by"` will represent the new 'insert' and therefore the proposed new value for the field.  Does  ' ...DB for the field is already not NULL,...' mean the field has  a `NOT NULL` constraint? If so and you are trying to catch a `NULL` value in the `UPDATE` it will not work as constraints are checked before triggers are run.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver the UPDATE statement doesn't have to pass updated_by. I want to ensure that it does. The db field has a NOT NULL constraint but that wouldn't stop an UPDATE statement from not updating updated_by

Comment: @AdrianKlaver "Due to MVCC updated_by will always be in the UPDATE", this is not true. I am able to run UPDATE statements that don't change the value of updated_by right now

Comment: I have edited the post to clarify the need

Comment: Are you just trying to track the database user and modification time of an updated row here? What does the updated_by field represent and is it constrained at all?

Comment: It is true, `updated_by` will always be there. It may not change but it will be there. If you want to catch changes you need to use something like `IF OLD.updated_by != NEW.updated_by THEN...`. If `NULL` values where involved then: `IF OLD.updated_by IS DISTINCT FROM NEW.updated_by THEN...`.

Comment: @JohnMorton for this purpose, it would just be the user, but not the db user. It's a web application user that the db cannot infer by itself. The updated_by has a NOT NULL constraint so that protects it from it being NULL during inserts, but I want to ensure that its value is updated on every UPDATE statement

Comment: @AdrianKlaver that unfortunately wouldn't work because it is totally possible for the same user to update the record as the one that had previously updated it. I don't want to raise an exception for that. I just want to raise an exception whenever the query itself doesn't pass updated_by

Comment: @AdrianKlaver right now I can perfectly run the following:

UPDATE table
SET column1 = value
WHERE table.id = 12345;

I don't have to include updated_by in there.

Comment: Then you can't do this on `updated_by` alone as there is no way of knowing that the same value came from the new query or not. You would have to bring in something like a sequence number or timestamp to distinguish them.

Comment: Doesn't matter `updated_by` will always be there. If you don't believe me add a `RAISE NOTICE %', NEW.updated_by;`

Comment: @AdrianKlaver, no I believe you. I wish there was a way to see what the db user was sending in as opposed too what the db engine generates.

Comment: Then I think that's a constraint you're going to have to place on the web application. As Adrian stated, there's no way to get at the fields specified in the UPDATE query, nor should you need to. The trigger only has access to the OLD values in the row and the NEW values in the row. Your web app should be what controls how a user is able to interact with your database, and it should be what is always including this field in your query.

Comment: @JohnMorton i guess it's not as easy to enforce that in the web service (developers can forget to pass the updated_by value in an UPDATE statement), so I was trying to enforce it at the db level. I appreciate both yours and Adrian's insight. Thank you